# Error 0 after changing server host

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am not familiar with Joomla at all, and I had to change our website's hosting service last week. I saved all data from the former one, exported the database, imported onto new server and uploaded all the files I had saved. 
I now have an Error 0 : "Contrôleur invalide" (in French, I'm not sure about the exact translation) and I have no idea how to fix it. It appears on the homepage, the menus at the top do appear, but not the drop downs on hover, and I have no access to the back-end ("mywebsite.com/administrator", worked fine before) : Chrome shows `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` when trying to access back-end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Homepage :
[image]
{ You may not be able to visit this page because of:

1. An out-of-date bookmark/favourite
2. A search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
3. A mistyped address
4. You have no access to this page
5. The requested resource was not found
6. An error has occurred while processing your request. }

Trying to access back-end :
[image]

Comment: I would suggest using Akeeba Backup to transfer the site over to your new host.

Comment: @Lodder How is it different from using Filezilla and doing it "manually" ?

Comment: for starting remove the old .htaccess file if it has been transferred and disable sef rewrite from global config. Also delete the contents of the cache folder if you have moved it as it was. See if these seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try also temporarily disabling any `php.ini` files in the root folder and in the `/administrator` folder by renaming them to `php.ini.old` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

For starting remove the old `.htaccess` file if it has been transferred and disable **sef rewrite** from **global config**.

Also delete the contents of the `cache` folder if you have moved it as it was. See if these seem to have any effect

*Note that the admin url is `www.example.com/administrator`

Comment: Did all of this, problem remains the same. Should I remove the contents of other cache files (like /admin/cache) ?

Comment: @Saryk Does it happen to try to load in the front-end something that requires its own connection to the database? It could be for example the fabrik component. *Note that the admin url is www.example.com/administrator

Comment: I have no idea... The site was developped a couple years ago, it's even possible the joomla version is older than 3.0.

Comment: What version of PHP is your hosting set to? Unless it is a fairly new version of Joomla, it won't run on PHP 7.

Comment: You also likely need to update the `tmp` and `logs`  paths in the `configuration.php` file to suit the new hosting although I doubt this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @NeilRobertson PHP version is 5.6

Comment: PHP 5.6 should be fine.

Comment: I'd be tempted to try disabling third party extensions via phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Saryk, also make sure that the restoration was ok and you don't have corrupted files. Maybe try once again. Also check this answer here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17203/front-end-db-error-back-end-works/17204#17204

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling gzip compression in the global configuration settings and see if that solves the problem. It might be that your new server does not support gzip compression.